# How to set textview with less and more links in Recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, textview, android-recyclerview

I have a `TextView`, which is used to show large texts with less and more links. I have this `TextView` in my `RecyclerView` adapter. When I start the app, it shows the correct texts, but when I scroll down and scroll up again, sometimes the texts disappear, sometimes the text gets exchanged and sometimes it doesn't appear again.

I am using the below code :

CreateView Holder code:

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        return new ListItemHolder(inflater.inflate(mLayoutResID, viewGroup, false));
}


@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    mList = (dataList) this.dataList.get(position);
final ListItemHolder listItemHolder = (ListItemHolder) viewHolder;

listItemHolder.mBodyText = mList.getmBody();
makeExpandable(listItemHolder.mBodyText, listItemHolder.mBodyTextView);
```

}

```
public void makeExpandable(String descriptionText, final TextView textView) {

    MORE = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.more_content);
    LESS = " " + mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.less_content);
    CharSequence body = Html.fromHtml(descriptionText);
    final SpannableString text = new SpannableString(body);
    mTitleBodyTextView = textView;

    final int maxChar = 150;
    final ViewTreeObserver vto = textView.getViewTreeObserver();
    textView.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            ViewTreeObserver obs = textView.getViewTreeObserver();
            obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            lineEndIndex = 150;
            textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            showLess(text, maxChar, textView);
        }
    });

}


/**
 * truncate text and append a clickable {@link #MORE}
 */
private void showLess(final SpannableString text, final int maxChar, final TextView textView) {

    final String newText = text.subSequence(0, lineEndIndex - (ELLIPSIZE.length() +
            MORE.length() + 1)).toString() + ELLIPSIZE + MORE;
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(newText);

    builder.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            showMore(text, maxChar, textView);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
            ds.setColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_dark));
        }
    }, newText.length() - MORE.length(), newText.length(), 0);

    textView.setText(builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}

/**
 * show full text and append a clickable {@link #LESS}
 */
private void showMore(final SpannableString text, final int maxChar, final TextView textView) {
    // create a text like subText + ELLIPSIZE + MORE
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text + LESS);

    builder.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            showLess(text, maxChar, textView);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
            ds.setColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_dark));
        }
    }, builder.length() - LESS.length(), builder.length(), 0);

    textView.setText(builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

}
```

Comment: Can you post the adapter code especially onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder

Comment: I have edited my code in the description of the question, please check it once and help me if you have any idea here.

Comment: Which is your list? Like ArrayList or something to set in adapter items ?

Comment: I do not have arrayList, it is custom list in which I have set my list item details.

Comment: May I have any solution for this issue. It would be a great help.

Comment: @PrithnirajNicyone I have similar problem. Please let me know if you found any solution.